# Unity3D MARS Geo Fencing Proxy Condition not Spawning on Physical Device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, geolocation, augmented-reality, geofencing

I am using a Geo Fencing condition.

I initially spawn an unlimited number of Horizontal Planes with a Synthetic Object component attached including a semantic tag.

I then instantiate a Prefab multiple time at runtime based on data from a database.

Each instantiated object has its own BoundaryBox specified with a unique lat/long.

The lat/long are set to five decimal places. The lat/long extents are set to 1e-04

This all works fine in the simulator using my current gps position as the simulated center.

However it is not working when deployed to a physical device : Android 11, Pixel 3 XL

I have tried with different Extents.

For info, I am requesting permission for FineLocation. This part appears to be working as I am able to print my device's lat/long to the screen.

But, no geofenced objects are appearing at all.

When I remove the geofence condition, the objects are spawned correctly.

I have experimented with having the condition disabled and then enabling it at runtime once it is configured as per advice I saw in an older thread.

I am working with Unity 2020.3.11f1

[image]

```
var geoFenceCondition = myPrefab.GetComponent<GeoFenceCondition>();
     
            var boundingBox= new GeographicBoundingBox
            {
                center = new GeographicCoordinate(46.34040,5.07097),
                latitudeExtents = 1e-04,
                longitudeExtents = 1e-04,
            };
     
            geoFenceCondition.BoundingBox=boundingBox;
```

Answer (score 1):

A support contact from Unity Technologies was able to help resolve this so I'll share the solution here.

Because the MARS db has it's own copies of various condition data in an optimal fomat, and because the condition checking runs on a background thread for performance, it is neccesary to call SyncModifications() method of the Proxy whenever changes are made to conditions at runtime.

"Calling SyncModifications() informs the query db of a change and schedules a "modification" change action. A modification change can take a few frames to get picked up, as the db query scheduling thread is synced intermittently with the main thread via an actions buffer."

Further info:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mars@1.3/api/Unity.MARS.Proxy.html

https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.mars@1.3/api/Unity.MARS.ProxyGroup.html